Drawing polygons using pyqt5
I am trying to create a program that allows users to draw different types of shapes by drawing simple lines using Pyqt5.
The program must detect if a shape is closed and then automatically fill the area inside of it with a defined color(for example red in this code)
Problem: the modification I need to add is if another line is drawn inside that polygon and divides the polygon into more pieces, the color inside that created zone can be changed into something else(for example blue for default) but also be editable(using the right click) to change into more color options and finally have a hover effect when mouse is moved on them as the user can feel the polygon is divided into different zones
I will include an example below for you to understand what I mean better along with the code.
First we create a simple polygon:

Then we try to divide it into different zones:

And here is my code:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsLineItem, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF,QLineF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush, QColor , QPolygonF

class UserLineItem(QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5))

    def p1(self):
        return self.line().p1()

    def p2(self):
        return self.line().p2()

    def setP1(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        if line.p1() != p:
            line.setP1(p)
            self.setLine(line)

    def setP2(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        if line.p2() != p:
            line.setP2(p)
            self.setLine(line)


class MeasuredGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    gridSpacing = 25
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(-500, -500, 1000, 1000)

        self.currentLine = None
        self.vertexLines = {}

    def drawBackground(self, qp, rect):
        normal = QPen(Qt.lightGray, 1, Qt.DotLine)
        dark = QPen(Qt.black, 1, Qt.DotLine)

        rect &= self.scene.sceneRect()
        left, top, right, bottom = rect.getCoords()

        qp.save()

        x = left // self.gridSpacing * self.gridSpacing
        while x <= right:
            if x == 0:
                qp.setPen(dark)
            else:
                qp.setPen(normal)
            qp.drawLine(QLineF(x, top, x, bottom))
            x += self.gridSpacing

        y = top // self.gridSpacing * self.gridSpacing
        while y <= bottom:
            if y == 0:
                qp.setPen(dark)
            else:
                qp.setPen(normal)
            qp.drawLine(QLineF(left, y, right, y))
            y += self.gridSpacing

        qp.restore()

    def removeCurrentLine(self):
        if self.currentLine:
            self.removeLineItem(self.currentLine)
            self.currentLine = None

    def removeLineItem(self, lineItem):
        if not isinstance(lineItem, QGraphicsLineItem):
            return
        line = lineItem.line()
        for p in (line.p1(), line.p2()):
            key = p.x(), p.y()
            if key in self.vertexLines:
                items = self.vertexLines[key]
                if lineItem in items:
                    items.remove(lineItem)
                if not items:
                    del self.vertexLines[key]
        self.scene.removeItem(lineItem)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        item = self.itemAt(pos)
        if isinstance(item, UserLineItem):
            menu = QMenu(self)
            menu.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

            deleteAction = menu.addAction('Delete')
            action = menu.exec_(event.globalPos())

            if action == deleteAction:
                self.removeLineItem(item)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if self.currentLine and event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            # discard the current line
            self.removeCurrentLine()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            p = self.snapToGrid(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            lines = self.vertexLines.setdefault((p.x(), p.y()), [])
            if len(lines) == 2:
                return
            self.currentLine = UserLineItem(QLineF(p, p))
            self.scene.addItem(self.currentLine)
            lines.append(self.currentLine)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if self.currentLine:
            endPoint = self.snapToGrid(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            if not self.scene.sceneRect().contains(endPoint):
                return
            self.currentLine.setP2(endPoint)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if not self.currentLine or event.button() != Qt.LeftButton:
            return

        if self.currentLine.line().isNull():
            # empty line (start and end are identical)
            self.removeCurrentLine()
            return

        endPoint = self.snapToGrid(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
        if not self.scene.sceneRect().contains(endPoint):
            # out of scene boundaries
            self.removeCurrentLine()
            return

        current = self.currentLine.line()
        startPoint = current.p1()
        key = endPoint.x(), endPoint.y()

        if not key in self.vertexLines:
            # new vertex
            self.vertexLines[key] = [self.currentLine]
            self.currentLine = None
            return

        lineItems = self.vertexLines[key]

        if len(lineItems) == 2:
            # the point already has two lines (is real a vertex)
            self.removeCurrentLine()
            return

        other = lineItems[0].line()
        if (
            other == current or (
                other.p2() == startPoint
                and other.p1() == endPoint
            )
        ):
            # a similar segment already exists
            self.removeCurrentLine()
            return

        lineItems.append(self.currentLine)

        self.fillShape(self.currentLine)

        self.currentLine = None

    def fillShape(self, reference):
        current = reference
        p = current.p1()

        polygon = [p] # the possible polygon
        toRemove = set() # line items that may be eventually removed

        while True:
            lineItems = self.vertexLines[p.x(), p.y()]
            if len(lineItems) == 1:
                # open path, ignore
                return

            toRemove |= set(lineItems)
            firstItem, lastItem = lineItems

            if firstItem == current:
                nextItem = lastItem
            else:
                nextItem = firstItem

            if nextItem == reference:
                # closed path, finalize polygon
                break

            if nextItem.p1() == p:
                p = nextItem.p2()
            else:
                p = nextItem.p1()

            polygon.append(p)
            current = nextItem

        self.scene.addPolygon(QPolygonF(polygon), QPen(Qt.black), QBrush(Qt.red))

        # remove line items and their vertexes
        for item in toRemove:
            self.removeLineItem(item)

    def snapToGrid(self, point):
        return QPointF(
            round(point.x() / self.gridSpacing) * self.gridSpacing, 
            round(point.y() / self.gridSpacing) * self.gridSpacing
        )

    def fill_shape(self):
        poly = self.scene.addPolygon(QPolygonF(self.current_shape), QPen(Qt.black), QBrush(Qt.red))

    def show_context_menu(self, pos):
        item = self.itemAt(pos)
        if isinstance(item, UserLineItem):
            global_pos = self.mapToGlobal(pos)
            context_menu = QMenu(self)
            delete_action = context_menu.addAction('Delete')
            action = context_menu.exec_(global_pos)

            if action == delete_action:
                self.scene.removeItem(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = MeasuredGraphicsView()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


What did you try? The code above is completely taken from my answer to your previous post, and there is no attempt in solving the issue here. Splitting is doable, but it's difficult especially for irregular shapes and even more for non convex polygons: you need to check if and where the line intercepts segments of the polygon, then "walk" each edge and compare with the interception. We cannot implement all that for you, at least try some attempts. See this related post.

You're right. I didn't change anything and this is the same code you modified for me, but I thought I still could ask?maybe I had no idea how to implement the changes I want but needed help still.
even though I must say I did try some things, but since the results were too out of the blue I thought maybe it's a better idea not to confuse people and share my working code.

User attempts don't confuse us, even if they don't work out as expected: addressing the problem from scratch does; the "working code" should at least try to solve the problem, right now it's almost like "I cannot do it, show me how you'd do it", which is not in the scope of StackOverflow. If you made multiple attempts, get the one that seems the most reasonable to you and show us: it may be appropriate in principle and we could tell you how to fix it, or we may even suggest a completely different approach, but in both cases at least you'd know what was wrong with your code.

Remember: learning from what others do is certainly important, but learning from what you understand about your mistakes is often even better. Please take your time and provide a proper [mre] that practically attempts to solve the problem, and if it works in some cases but not in others, ensure that you properly explain the procedure you followed in those different cases.
